# I need to filter all the userGroups from this JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json, .net-core, json-deserialization

TaskProperty.InternalAppConfiguration defines a JSON with various information and I need to **get all the userGroups** from this JSON. I only need names of the userGroups.

```
                    // saving task properties
                    foreach (var TaskProperty in representation.TaskProperties != null ? representation.TaskProperties : new List<TaskProperty>())
                    {
                        await this.taskRepository.AddTaskPropertyAsync(new TaskProperty()
                        {
                            ConnectionId = TaskProperty.ConnectionId,
                            NodeId = result.VertexIdPairs[Convert.ToInt16(TaskProperty.NodeId)],
                            TaskId = TaskProperty.TaskId,
                            InternalAppConfiguration = TaskProperty.InternalAppConfiguration,
                            IsApprovalTask = TaskProperty.IsApprovalTask
                        });
                    };
```

my JSON is looks like this,

[image]

in JSON visualizer it looks like this

[image]

how can I store all the userGroups into a single array or a list or something I can use in the future?
I've tried to deserialize using Newtonsoft, but I was unable to do anything. please help me out.. I really appreciate your answers and suggesions. Thank you!

Comment: Plz let know how much you tried using Newtonsoft!

Comment: @mahesh_b I Didn't know how to format my helper class to map this JSON..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Newtonsoft, this is what I would do:

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetNamesFromJson(string json)
    {
        InternalAppConfiguration jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InternalAppConfiguration>(json);
        return jsonObject.OptionsData.UserGroups.Select(ug => ug.DisplayName);
    }

    public class InternalAppConfiguration
    {
        public OptionsData OptionsData { get; set; }
    }

    public class OptionsData
    {
        public List<UserGroup> UserGroups { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserGroup
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: it worked for me .. thank you so much! I really appreciate that @devcrp